# Git: How to revert/undo a massive merge?

Tags: git

First off, I know there's a ton of merge-related answers in StackOverflow already. I just spent the better part of an hour combing through them trying to figure this out...

My problem is that I have a very old branch, branch A (say from 2017). I wanted to bring it up to date, so I merged from master (which is up to date, circa 2019) and pushed. This added a very large number of commits to the history. I've been told after the fact I need to update branch A with branch B instead of master... how can I get rid of just the master merge and return branch A to its original state?

Maybe I should just use "git revert X" and eat the terrible history it will leave?

Most of the answers I've seen mention checking out the "last known good" commit before the merge, but I don't know that commit hash and the history has literal years of commits in it now from my merge. I do know the commit hash of my merge commit - let's call it X. My assumption was that the LKG commit then would be X^1, which I've looked at with "git log X^1". However, I want to be certain this is correct before I change the branch history, and I'm having a very difficult time looking at the commits around X^1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is actually to get rid of all of those revisions that came from master as in *you never merged*, then you should `git reset --hard` (providing the id of the revision where A was before... check `git reflog` or the log of the branch)... then it is like whatever you did **never happened**.

Comment: "git reflog" is EXACTLY what I wanted. Thank you. Amazing I didn't see this on any other answers...